# Two ways of smooth dragging a vector on a Lie group

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

I know two ways of dragging a vector tangent to the Lie group $G$ from $T_gG$ to $T_eG$:

1. Using Maurer-Cartan form $\theta$ which acts as a push-forward of the left group translation by $g^{-1}$:
   $$\theta(X|_g) = L_{g^{-1}*}(X|_g)$$
2. Using Lie transportation. I guess, nothing stops me form finding such vector field $Y$ that dragging $X$ along $Y$ would move $X$ to $e$.

Can these two be reduced to each other?

Comment: I am not sure, what you are really looking for. For the second mehtod, you need to choose a vector field, whose flow maps $e$ to $g$. There are many such choices, and there is no reason to expect that the resulting linear isomorphisms $T_gG\to T_eG$  should be related to each other or to the one induced by left translation.